# Merging iris when cube.var_name differs

Tags: python-iris

I’ve run into a problem with merging cubes.  I have a cube list that I would like to merge into a smaller set of cubes. 
However, when I try and merge iris gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/iris/cube.py", line 377, in merge_cube
    proto_cube.register(cube, error_on_mismatch=True)
  File "site-packages/iris/_merge.py", line 1260, in register
    error_on_mismatch)
  File "site-packages/iris/_merge.py", line 420, in match
    raise iris.exceptions.MergeError(msgs)
iris.exceptions.MergeError: failed to merge into a single cube.
  cube.var_name differs: u'air_pressure_at_sea_level_0' != u'air_pressure_at_sea_level_2'
```

I’m using Iris version 1.13.0 with python 2.7.

I have tried removing the var_name coordinate but got an exception when I did cube.remove_coord('var_name'):

```
iris.exceptions.CoordinateNotFoundError: 'Expected to find exactly 1  coordinate, but found none.'
```

Other than this detail, I consider the two cubes to be suitable for merging and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_name` is an attribute on a cube (and, as it happens, on coordinates) and it is this that differs between your two cubes.

Simply homogenising your `var_names` should be all that is needed in this instance. For example, you might want to set them all to `air_pressure_at_sea_level` with:

```
for cube in cubes:
    cube.var_name = 'air_pressure_at_sea_level'
```

After that, `cubes.merge_cube()` should work (or potentially raise a further incompatibility).

Comment: I also note that cube coordinates also have a var_name.  Therefore it may also be necessary to apply a similar process to these.  For instance: `cube.coord("latitude").var_name = "latitude"` (depending on how messed up your input cube is.